# How to terminate spring boot application process in Windows by pressing Control-C?

Tags: java, windows, spring-boot, control-c

If I run a spring boot application from within a Windows Command Prompt (using java -jar), and I press Control-C to terminate the process, I get the following console output, and the process remains opened:

```
2017-11-27 20:15:22,713 INFO [Thread-11] (AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext:984) - Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6057aebb: startup date [Mon Nov 27 20:14:22 IST 2017]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2df9b86
```

I use the following code in order to listen to the ContextClosedEvent.

```
@Component
public class ListenerClass {
      @EventListener
      public void handleContextClose(ContextClosedEvent event) {
          shutdown(); // This method has System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(ctx)); inside it
      }
    }
```

I tried adding the following code to the above-mentioned ListenerClass, but it didn't solve this issue:

```
  @EventListener
  public void handleContextStop(ContextStoppedEvent event) {
      shutdown();
  }
```

How can I cause the application to terminate when Control-C is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

Your listener is not being reached (verify using debugger). Otherwise System.exit would kill all the threads - by the way, it is bad practice.

You should connect to your JVM up and running via jvisualvm, and check the live thread(s) once you hit ^C